# Just opened up a defunct Samsung charger... what am I looking at?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, pcb, resistors, integrated-circuit

[image]

From a preliminary look around the internet, I think there's an axial lead capacitor, a couple of ceramic capacitors, and a couple of electrolytic capacitors.

I'm also thinking that that's a resistor down the bottom there.

[image]

In this second one, I recon I'm looking at a bunch of IC's and transistors, but, beyond knowing the two basic transistor types (PNP and NPN), I don't really know how further to identify them.

Any confirmation or correction on anyone's part would be great!

Comment: Resources for teardowns of chargers - [Ken Shirriff's blog](http://www.righto.com/2012/10/a-dozen-usb-chargers-in-lab-apple-is.html) and [Big Clive on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/user/bigclivedotcom)

Comment: No relevance to the question, but what an interestingly odd inclusion of dimensions on the silkscreen of the lower image (3 places).

Comment: Creepage distances, usually on the compliance documentation.

Comment: @jesser2: Nobody has mentioned yet the carpet! Most of the area you are looking at is carpet.

Comment: Ugly cheap slave labor manually built board..  How many of their phones blew up again?

Comment: @AnalogKid ... Ah yes, that makes sense. I hadn't seen it noted on the silkscreen before. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The component with a "F" designator (light green) is a fuse. The "TH" (dark green) is a PTC thermistor. The "L" (vertical black cylinder) is an inductor.

And I think the charger failed because a thermal fuse (connected via the wire over the core) on the transformer blew, so thermal damage (as the half-shattered core and partially-melted cap evidence).

Answer (score 1):

The two horizontal tubular parts are electrolytic capacitors.  The top right black cylindrical part that is standing up also appears to be electrolytic capacitors.  The bottom left standing-up part seems to be inductor.

The blue sortof disk at middle right could be a capacitor, but might also be a TVS or varistor.

The green part at lower left could also be various things.  The "T" designator hints at a temperature sensor, like a thermistor.

The green part at lower right seems to be a fuse.  A resistor would have more obvious markings, and the "F" in the part designator is a clue.

Comment: Middle-right smells like a Y-class cap ("CY").

Comment: @Ign: That's plausible.